# Magento 2 : Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed, ALTER TABLE customer_group

Tags: magento2, database, customer, foreign-key

After upgrade from magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.3 and am stuck. I have tried everything.

> In Pdo.php line 235:
>       SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './zwwnzwzjhe/#sql-1bd1_25f9' to './zwwnzwzjhe/customer_group' (errno:
>   150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed), query was: ALTER
>   TABLE `customer_group` MODIFY COLUMN `customer_group_id` int(10)
>   UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> In Pdo.php line 228:    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './zwwnzwzjhe/#sql-1bd1_25f9' to
>   './zwwnzwzjhe/customer_group' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed)

I am unable to delete this table or make any changes to this table ...please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To work around this, use either of these solutions. Both present risks of damaging the data integrity.

Option 1:

```
Remove constraints
Perform TRUNCATE
Delete manually the rows that now have references to nowhere
Create constraints
```

Option 2:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
TRUNCATE table customer_group; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: nothing works I am unable to delete manually due to foreign key, Option 2 also doesnt work 

when i truncate, I get the


Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`zwwnzwzjhe`.`catalog_product_bundle_price_index`, CONSTRAINT `catalog_product_bundle_price_index_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `zwwnzwzjhe`.`customer_group` (`customer_) 16:14:18 SQL command

Comment: @roger even when you are using second option ?

Comment: Yes

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.000 s) Edit

TRUNCATE table customer_group
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.023 s) Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.000 s) Edit

Comment: Query seems to be executed , i don't see any errors @roger

Comment: 0 rows affected. i still get the same error so I am guessing now effect is taking place

Comment: @roger i am assuming that you are trying to truncate the data customer_group  , please replace TRUNCATE table customer_group;  with the table name you are trying truncate

Comment: I am not sure i understand ?- i am unable to truncate customer_group table - the customer_group_id is the primary - I am also unable to delete or truncate