# upgrade issue from 2.1.14 to 2.2 :: magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, magento2.2, magento-upgrade

I have upgrade magento version from **2.1.14** to **2.2.0**.

First time when i run run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command it gives this error:

```
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_BundleStaging':
Upgrading schema.. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './databasem2/#sql-3b4_94f' to './databasem2/catalog_product_bundle_selection' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
```

Now every time upgrade command gives this error:

```
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_BundleStaging':
Upgrading schema.. SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sequence_product_bundle_option' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE sequence_product_bundle_option (
                     sequence_value integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                     PRIMARY KEY (sequence_value)
            ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 0 ENGINE = INNODB
```

I have try to remove tables but it gives same error.

I have read this [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264178/magento-2-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-alter-table-customer-g) and [link2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12434) but still not working for me.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this? post your answer

Comment: no, i have disable this "Magento_BundleStaging" module and then upgrade.